# CC Colpitts oscillator calculations

Tags: rf, oscillator

[image][image]

I'm trying to make a low inductance measurement using CC Clapp oscillator.

I calculate things, I get strange results.

Would someone please write me the formula solving for Lx?

And how do I calculate the total capacitance here, are they all in series?
I applied to this formula \$\frac{1}{6.28f}^2 C\$.

Comment: show your calculations, please!

Comment: Thanks first, when I get 60 MHz on the counter and I presume the capacitanc is 1.5exp-11, then I get 1.056exp-4!!!

Comment: No, please *actually* show us your calculations, not only what you get.

Comment: What do you mean by "low inductance measurement"?  Do you mean you're sticking an unknown inductor into a Clapp oscillator to measure it's inductance?

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses,
Yes that's exactly what I do (see image please)
I've built mor than 4 LC meters with PIC micro and Arduino LM311, 319, but never satisfied with range and precision especially below 10uH.
I wanted this circuit as a down range or below 10u.
Due to my modest math_ebgineering knowledge, Ican't decide between this nethod and the variable frequency generator banging a resonant circuit.

Comment: Why do you call it a Clapp oscillator when your title says Colpitts?

Comment: A mistake! Sorry! I wonder why it isn't so easy somene simply tell me whether I should add up the four Capacitors, or is it only C4 that matters in the outcoming frequency, I wouldn't bother asking if I found an easy way to learn myself if it weren't from books and publications  only detaling calculus and internet sites monopoly only requiring registering etc. Where you spend hours and get nothing!